# Deploy android app from Eclipse on both Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha B and C simulators running simultaneously

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10

I've set both simulators as targets in Eclipse but it's impossible to run app on B simulator and right after that run it on C simulator. Eclipse doesn't find one of them (it's set up in "target" settings but is unrechable when I try to deploy an app).

So, at the moment I need to change my "target" settings in Eclipse every time I want to test app on different simulator (and often (or even always, I'm not 100% sure - just don't remeber) Eclipse even isn't able to deploy app on another simulator without closing previous emulator/cleaning all simulators settings/ restarting eclipse...). For example: I set simulator B as default target and deploy app on it, after that I set simulator C as default , but app is deployed again to B!

**How can I deploy android app from Eclipse on both Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha B anc C simulators running simultaneously?**

Additional info:

- I have latest version of Blackberry 10 simulators and of Android and Blackberry development software for Eclipse
- I run simulators in Vmware

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you reslove your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to deploy on several devices at one time from Eclipse. With the current version of the plugin at least (I hope this will be added soon).

But maybe the command line would be better suited for you. If you just write a little script that calls all commands (one for each device). You can just run that script whenever you want to deploy.

```
command_to_deploy_on_Dev_Alpha_B
command_to_deploy_on_Dev_Alpha_C
```

Not really 'simultaneous', but close enough I guess